# How to make cylinder tangents to the sphere shape in three.js or with the red line

Tags: 3d, three.js, vector-graphics

I want to add a cylinder perpendicular to a sphere or whatever organic object base on the normal direction of the mesh I want to target but the cylinder is not tangents whatever I have done

```
I have this
```

[image]

```
this is the best I have achieved but is not what I want the cylinder is not tangent
```

[image]

```
cylinder(position: THREE.Vector3, radius: number, height: number, name: string = 'cylinder') {
        const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( radius, radius, height, 32 );
        geometry.translate( 0, height / 2, 0 );
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
        const normal_material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({transparent: true, opacity: 0.4});
        const cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, normal_material );
        cylinder.position.set(position.x, position.y, position.z);
        // this.scene.add( cylinder );
        return cylinder;
    }




const cylinder = this.examples.cylinder(p, 2.0, 5.0, `cylinder_a_${this.points.length}`);

    cylinder.geometry.rotateX((-94 * Math.PI) / 180);
    cylinder.lookAt(this.intersection.normal);

    // const vector = new THREE.Vector3(100, 60, 20);
    // const axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    // cylinder.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(axis, b.clone().normalize());
    this.scene.add( cylinder );
```

### I try and this but for some reason is not accurate

```
const position = p;
    const length = 9.99;
    const radius = 2.0;
    const depth = 0.0;
    const name = `cylinder_a_${this.points.length}`;
    const cylinder = this.examples.cylinder(position, radius, length, depth, name);

    cylinder.geometry.rotateX((90 * Math.PI) / 180);
    cylinder.lookAt( cylinder.position.clone().add(this.intersection.normal) );

    this.scene.add( cylinder );
```

[image]

Comment: Try to change: `cylinder.geometry.rotateX((-94 * Math.PI) / 180);` => `cylinder.geometry.rotateX(Math.PI * 0.5);`

Comment: Thanx but is not working

Comment: I want to aline the cylinder with the red line

Comment: When you do this `cylinder.lookAt(this.intersection.normal);`, it means that you pointing your object (along its z-axis) at the position, relatively to the center of the scene. Try something like: `cylinder.lookAt(cylinder.position.clone().add(this.intersection.normal));`. If position of the cylinder equals to the point of intersection.

Comment: Ooo bro this worked thank you

Comment: I dont know why but I have 1.2 o angle lost

Comment: How do you draw the line?

Comment: i have a function that works like helper to see where the cylinder is gonna render when the use is gonna click - select the point where he wants the cylinder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167756/discussion-between-prisoner849-and-george).